# How to download a full multi-paged news article?

Tags: firefox, downloads

When I visit a site like the New York Times, I sometimes like to save the page for offline viewing. But many of the articles are linked in a series, like page 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Is there a way to save the entire article across multiple pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some websites offer a way to download the entire article, a single page, or any variation of those *without* the need for the browser's function.

## New York Times

(Since "Save" on NYT apparently requires an account of some sorts - haven't had to deal with the NYT site *that* much, tbh - I'm going with the "definitely working" way as follows)

In the case of this random [New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/01/18/world/africa/algeria-militants-hostages.html), you can use the "Single Page" option:

[image: Single Page]

This displays the entire article on one page. Subsequently, you can choose the "Print" option (also shown in the screenshot) to get a raw text of the entire article.

## Other sites

Nowadays, the whole "multi-page news article" thing is largely being taken back. Most news sites use a blog format that uses vertical space - as in: Site gets long, but all the content is on one page - so there is barely any need for this.

But on the sites that do still have this, you'll most likely find something like the above. Some way of displaying it all on one page, or some link to "Print Whole Article" - something like that. Mostly, you'll have to find it yourself, though, as these links are in no way standardized. No external script could *reliably* gather them *universally* and tie the whole article together. You won't find anything that will do this for *all* sites. It might exist for *some*, but then you'll have tons of scripts running ... Not exactly the fanciest ways of running a computer.

A nice example extension I just found, which requires scrolling to the end of the article to get it all loaded, however, is ["AutoPager"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autopager/) (Link to Firefox version, exists for other browsers as well, I believe).

If the site's developers just didn't think of this as being necessary, and you can't find a utility, your best bet is to contact their support and make them take note of it, if you believe it worth the hassle.

Comment: +1 for contacting support and requesting the feature.